# Delete specific days name between two date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to delete specific days by name from two date (Start Date | End Date ) in SQL Server like example

```
START DATE "12/12/2020" END DATE "30/12/2020"
```

In this two date I removed from all week Monday and count days without Monday.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do.

Comment: You don't need to SHOUT(!!) at us, your normal inside voice is fine; we can read you fine without the CAPS.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: This question looks suspiciously similar to [this one on the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/960016e2-a0d5-4c9f-9a32-ff4bd0229c9b/remove-days-name-from-all-week-in-query-between-two-dates?forum=transactsql). It seems students are looking for help with the same homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `datename()` to get the name of the day:

```
declare @startdate date = '2020-12-12'
declare @enddate date = '2020-12-30'

select count(*)
from tablename
where datecolumn between @startdate and @enddate
and datename(w, datecolumn) <> 'Monday';
```

Comment: thank you so much but I don't understand this row 'where datecolumn between "startdate" and "enddate" ' exactly datecolumn

Comment: In my code `datecolumn` is the column of your table that contains the date. You must change it with the actual name of the column. In the WHERE clause the condition is that the date must be between the startdate and enddate that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
delete from t
    where date >= @startdate and date <= @enddate and
          datename(weekday, date) = 'Monday';
```

Comment: I think you mean WEEKDAY or even DW not dow.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I don't think I've ever written it correctly the first time.  `dow` just seems like the name for the date part.

Comment: In my little head too.